# How to get columns from multiple rows in a single row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to get 2 columns col_a and col_b's values for min and max of some other column. For example:

| id | last_updated | col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | abc | xyz |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | abc_0 | xyz_0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | abc_1 | xyz_1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | abc_2 | xyz_2 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | abc | xyz |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | abc | xyz |
| ... |  |  |  |

I want to get the result:

```
|1|abc|abc_2|xyz|xyz_2|
```

That is the result of grouping by id, and getting the values of these columns while putting the condition of min and max on some other column(last_updated).

I came up with the following query:

```
select id, max(last_updated), min(last_updated)
from my_table
group by id
```

This gives me the id and min and max dates but not the other 2 columns. I'm not sure how to get the values for the other 2 columns for both dates in same query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MIN` and `MAX` analytical function as follows:

```
select id,
       max(case when mindt = last_updated then col_a end) as min_col_a,
       max(case when maxdt = last_updated then col_a end) as max_col_a,
       max(case when mindt = last_updated then col_b end) as min_col_b,
       max(case when maxdt = last_updated then col_b end) as max_col_b
  from
(select t.*,
       min(last_updated) over (partition by id) as mindt,
       max(last_updated) over (partition by id) as maxdt
  from your_table t) t
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER`, twice, to find the first and last rows, as ordered by `last_updated`, for each `id` group of records.  Then, aggregate by `id` and pivot out columns for the various `col_a` and `col_b` values.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY last_updated) rn_min,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY last_updated DESC) rn_max
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 THEN col_a END) AS col_a_min,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_max = 1 THEN col_a END) AS col_a_max,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 THEN col_b END) AS col_b_min,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_max = 1 THEN col_b END) AS col_b_max
FROM cte
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: How can I get these in separate columns? I've updated the question

Comment: Answer updated.  Your original question made it seem that you wanted a CSV string.

Answer (score 2):

Not the neatest solution but demonstrates another way to obtain the data you want. We join the table on itself as we normally want data from 2 rows, then we use `cross apply` to restrict it to first and last.

```
select T1.id, T2.col_a, T1.col_a, T2.col_b, T1.col_b
from #my_table T1
inner join #my_table T2 on T1.id = T2.id
cross apply (
  select id, max(last_updated) MaxLastUpdated, min(last_updated) MinLastUpdated
  from #my_table
  group by id
) X
where T1.last_updated = X.MaxLastUpdated and T2.last_updated = X.MinLastUpdated;
```

With the sample data provided this appear to perform worse than the `row_number()` solution. The fastest solution is the analytical functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,max(last_updated) last_updatedMax, min(last_updated) last_updatedMin,max(col_aMax) col_aMax, max(col_aMin) col_aMin,max(col_bMax) col_bMax, max(col_bMin) col_bMin
from
(
    select 
        *
        , first_value(col_a) OVER (PARTITION BY  id ORDER BY last_updated desc) as  col_aMax
        , first_value(col_a) OVER (PARTITION BY  id ORDER BY last_updated asc) as  col_aMin
        , first_value(col_b) OVER (PARTITION BY  id ORDER BY last_updated desc) as  col_bMax
        , first_value(col_b) OVER (PARTITION BY  id ORDER BY last_updated asc) as  col_bMin
     from my_table
) t
group by id
```